# In Moose, how can I make a class's constructor return an instance of a subclass?

Tags: perl, constructor, subclass, moose

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to have Moose return a child class instance instead of its own class, for polymorphism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2994072/how-to-have-moose-return-a-child-class-instance-instead-of-its-own-class-for-pol)

Suppose I have two related classes MyClass::A and MyClass::B that are both subclasses of MyClass. I would like the constructor for MyClass to take a filename, read the file, and based on the contents of the file, decide whether the file is of type A or B. Then, it should construct an object of the appropriate subclass and return it. **Edit:** Actually, it should call the constructor of the appropriate subclass and return the result.

So for example, after this code,

```
my $filename = "file_of_type_A.txt";
my $object = MyClass->new($filename);
```

`$object` should be an instance of MyClass::A. This seems like valid behavior, because `$object->isa('MyClass')` will always return true. I was thinking of using introspection to get a list of all subclasses of MyClass, and then trying to construct each in turn, until one succeeds. However, I don't see a way to modify the Moose constructor to do this. Neither the BUILDARGS nor BUILD hooks seem appropriate.

So how can I modify a Moose class's constructor to select an appropriate subclass and delegate construction to that subclass?

Comment: I was typing an answer and suddenly got a sense of deja vu, realizing that [this has come up before in an earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2994072/how-to-have-moose-return-a-child-class-instance-instead-of-its-own-class-for-pol). To wit: you should call a factory method, which will decide which class's constructor it needs to call.

Comment: Yep, it's a duplicate all right. Vote to close.

Comment: Well, now I finally understand what a factory is for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Ether said above, you should have a factory method do this task.  I like to put the factory method in a separate package/class from the things it produces Usually this is a virtual class that has no attributes or constructor, but if you want to do things like keep track of what you have made, you can create an actual factory object.

```
package MyFile::Factory;

sub make_file_object {
    my $class = shift;
    my $filepath = shift;

    my $type = $class->determine_file_type( $filepath );
    my $file_class = $class->get_class_for_file_type( $type );

   return $file_class->new( $filepath, @_ );
}

# implement those other methods down here.

1;
```

Comment: Then I would use the factory like this? `my $object = MyFile::Factory->make_file_object($filepath)`

Comment: Also, should the common superclass now become a role instead? The only reason I wanted it to be a class in the first place was to give it a constructor, and if I'm using a factory instead, then there's no need for that.

Comment: Your factory class isn't part of the MyFile inheritance hierarchy.  It sits alongside and acts on the hierarchy.